# Android PDF to Base64 conversion is not working

Tags: android, pdf, base64

I am trying upload one file PDF file to server. for that I need to convert the PDF file to BASE64 string.

the conversion is happening but when I am trying to do Base64 to PDF it is not giving proper value. I am getting error like below image .

Android code,
**file choosing code**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );

    if (requestCode == PDF_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        uri = data.getData();
        //String path=data.getData().getPath();
        btnPdfFileChooser.setText( "PDF is Selected" );
        //Toast.makeText(FileUploadActivity.this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //InputStream inputStream = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path)
        PdfUploadFunction();
    }
}
```

**Upload function (need to write the API call to update the details in server. it is pending now.)**

```
private void PdfUploadFunction() {
    // Getting pdf name from EditText.
    PdfNameHolder = strPdfFileName.toString().trim();
    // Getting file path using Filepath class.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath( this, uri );
    }
    // If file path object is null then showing toast message to move file into internal storage.
    if (PdfPathHolder == null) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Please move your PDF file to internal storage & try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
    // If file path is not null then PDF uploading file process will starts.
    else {
        String base64 = getBase64FromPath( PdfPathHolder );
        //String base64 = encodeFileToBase64Binary( PdfPathHolder );
        Toast.makeText( this, "base64-" + base64, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( "base64-", base64.toString() );
    }
}
```

**BASE64 conversion code.**

```
 public static String getBase64FromPath(String path) {
      
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            File file = new File( path );
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

I have google it a lot. but I am not able to find any correct solution for this. hope somebody can help.

[image]

Comment: Start by deleting `FileUtils` -- use `c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` (based on your commented-out line). Then, reconsider your entire approach, as your app will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` for larger PDFs. Beyond that, you will need take a step-by-step approach to figuring out where things are going wrong, as we do not know how that screenshot relates to your code. For example, you might start by writing your base64-encoded data to a local file, transferring it to your development machine, decoding it there, and seeing if you get the correct PDF content.

Comment: The screen shot is from `https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf` here I pasted my base64 code to verify that generated one is correct or not.

Comment: That approach assumes that you are able to put the entire base64 encoded content into your clipboard. That may or may not be the case. For example, if you use `Log` statements to print your base64 value, Logcat does not display the complete values for really long content. There may also be clipboard length limits imposed by your operating system or Web browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your advice let try to send those values to server and  try

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getBase64Pdf(String pdfFilePath){
try{
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFilePath);
    byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    String encodedPdfString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"pdf converted to string : " + encodedPdfString);
    return encodedPdfString;
}catch (IOException e){
}
return "";
```

> Not sure about your scenario but this is working in my case maybe there is some issue with a path on your side